# Reconfigure Puphpet for PHP 5.5 installation or is there an alternative to it with PHP 5.5 support?

Tags: php, lamp, php-5.5, puphpet

I really like Puphpet, but looks like they dropped support for PHP 5.5, which I really really need.

Is there smth easy to use & similar/alternative to Puphpet or is there an easy way to change the Puphpet configuration to install PHP 5.5 for nginx/apache + php-fpm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the repo PuPHPet uses is the Ondrej PPA which no longer supports PHP <= 5.5.

If you're using CentOS, Remi's PHP repo is used which *does* still support older versions of PHP.